# How to save BitmapImage / WriteableBitmap in png format (Silverlight/windows phone)?

Tags: silverlight, image, png, save, windows-phone-7

How can i save an image (BitmapImage / WriteableBitmap) in png format using Silverlight for windows phone?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ImageTools](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/) on codeplex.  That supports silverlight encoding PNG.  I'm not sure whether this will work with or can be compiled for windows phone 7.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code.

This code worked for me. Before you try, make sure that your writablebitmap has a transparent background (You can check by assigning to a image controller image source). If not, make the background transparent from the controller it was coming from.

```
var localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("temp.png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
using (var ras = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite, StorageOpenOptions.None))
{
     WriteableBitmap bitmap = imageSource;
     var stream = bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
     byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
     await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
     BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, ras);
     encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, (uint)bitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)bitmap.PixelHeight, 96.0, 96.0, buffer);
     await encoder.FlushAsync();
}
```